# MongoDB upgrade from 3.4 to 3.6 fails

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB on a Windows2012 R2 Server.

The initial installation was MongoDB 3.2 and I'd like to upgrade it to 3.6.

This is what I've done so far:

1. stop mongod, exchange the binaries folder with 3.4 binaries
2. started mongod.exe service, checked version -> all fine (3.4 now)
3. set Compatibility Version to 3.4 (successful)

Now I'd like to upgrade from 3.4 to 3.6 and tried the exact same workflow, but I cant start mongod after switching the binary folder.

I just get a "**didnt responed in timely fashion**" when trying to start the mongod service. No mongo logging is written.

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I tried starting the mongod process per command shell to at least get some information as to why it won't start. Maybe that is somehow helpful:

[...] 2018-04-27T12:44:51.394+0200 I - [initandlisten] Detected data files in E :\mongodb\data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'. 2018-04-27T12:44:51.395+0200 I STORAGE [initandlisten] **exception in initAndList en: InvalidOptions: Requested option conflicts with current storage engine optio n for directoryPerDB; you requested false but the current server storage is alre ady set to true and cannot be changed, terminating** 2018-04-27T12:44:51.397+0200 I NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets... 2018-04-27T12:44:51.398+0200 I CONTROL [initandlisten] now exiting 2018-04-27T12:44:51.398+0200 I CONTROL [initandlisten] shutting down with code: 100

Comment: Are the data files the same? What if you flip the directoryPerDB option in the config file (as the error suggests)?

Comment: Yes, data files are the same. I also tried both config options (true&false) for the "directoryPerDB", but I always get the same message I quoted above.

Comment: How do you run the mongod in the command line? Does it _use_ that config file? Looks like it doesn't

Comment: You're right, I was doing that wrong. Correcting that by using "--config <path>" led me to the acutal issue I had to fix. I'll write an answer to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the following lines in the "net:" section of my config file to be able to start mongoDB 3.6:

```
http:
   enabled: false
   JSONPEnabled: false
   RESTInterfaceEnabled: false
```

I'm not sure yet if removing those lines will have any other impact on my DB, though.